# Invalid Request Error: Could not determine which URL to request: Stripe::Customer instance has invalid ID: nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I'm trying to implement Stripe payment onto my site. My associations, creditcard belongs to a user, and a user has many credit cards. Here's my `credit_card_service` code:

```
    class CreditCardService
     def initialize(user_id, card)
     @user = User.find(user_id)
     @card = card
    end

    def create_credit_card
     customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(@user.customer_id)
     customer.sources.create(source: generate_token).id
    end

    def generate_token
     Stripe::Token.create(
      card: {
       number: @card[:number],
       exp_month: @card[:month],
       exp_year: @card[:year],
       cvc: @card[:cvc]
      }
    ).id
  end
end
```

I get this error when I want my users to save their credit cards:

> Could not determine which URL to request: Stripe::Customer instance has invalid ID: nil

This line of code is the one that I think is causing problems:

```
customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(@user.customer_id)
```

but I don't know what the problem is. I don't understand how my Customer ID is `nil`. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried `puts @user.customer_id` before that line to check the value?

Comment: Yeah, it's nil.

#<User id: 1, email: "achie@gmail.com", created_at: "2018-11-22 06:39:54", updated_at: "2018-11-22 06:41:09", first_name: "Linda", last_name: nil, gender: nil, gender_preferences: nil, description: "City girl", photo: nil, provider: nil, uid: nil, name: nil, image: nil, customer_id: nil>

Comment: okay, set the customer_id on `@user` before calling `retrieve`

Comment: I can do that manually, but I need a solution for the users who will be using this service. Anything?